# How can I get value of QGenericArgument?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a [`QList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) of [`QGenericArgument`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericargument.html) in my application (to implement my event handlers class). In one specific case, I need to extract to value of an argument to do some checking. I know the type. So I wrote this:

```
template <class T>
T GetQArgumentValue(QGenericArgument &arg)
{
    const unsigned char* data = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(arg.data());
    return (T) *data;
}
```

And use like this:

```
QGenericArgument arg = Q_ARG(int, 30); // this is obviously an example, I get this from an array in real code
int value = GetQArgumentValue<int>(arg);
```

It works well. So my question are:

1) Since it's an internal helper class is there any issue of using it in my application?

2) Is there any built-in function to do this? I prefer built-in ones over re-invent the wheel.

**edit:**

What I want is this:

let's assume I have:

```
QGenericArgument arg = Q_ARG(int, 30);
```

I want to retrieve the `30` value back:

`int v = magic_function<int>(arg); // v = 30`

Comment: What is your use case? `QGenericArgument` is used only for `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`.

Comment: I created a custom class where I have a `QList` of `QGenericArgument` where them get eventually passed to `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`

Comment: This question suffers a bit from the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It'd be more useful if you told us *why* you need these generic arguments. What is your use case? Describe at a high level what you're trying to do, perhaps there's a better solution that doesn't depend on `QGenericArgument`.

Answer (score 3):

In the Qt documentation it is not advised to use `QGenericArgument` in any way exept of creating it by `Q_ARG` for passing to `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`. The reason is that the class `QGenericArgument` is actually a pair of two pointers (class members): `void*` for data and `const char*` for name.

It will work. However, it is similar to a list of void pointers and it is also bad in the same way.

If you pass such list to any function you should take care about life time of those objects: original objects pointed by those pointers should be still valid for enough time and also it is tricky with desruction of such objects.

If you need to manage some dynamic list of arguments before passing them to QMetaMethod it is safer and nicer to use some wrapper for those arguments. For example, there is the class [`QVariant`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) in Qt. So, `QList` of `QVariant` or `QVariantMap` can be used here.

Comment: I'm aware to most of this. What I'm trying to do is a list of events that eventually gets called. Roughly, similar to QT internal implementation that fires `loadFinished` when the page loading is done.